# Overload resolution failed on Math.Ceiling

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have the following error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible '*Ceiling*' can be called without a narrowing conversion.

My code is:

```
dgiOpr01Rep.Cells(7).Text = AddPrecZero(Math.Ceiling(dtgCollections.Items(i).Cells(7).Text))
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: More code required, but for starters Math.Ceiling() does not accept a parameter of type String. You will have to convert your string to a double or decimal using Convert.ToDouble() or Convert.ToDecimal().

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure that your title describes the problem - use the tags to describe the environment.

Comment: In your project properties or at the top of your code file, add Option Strict On

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the compiler is saying that it can't choose which overload to use without further information

Try converting the text value to a numeric type first, for example:

```
Dim val As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(dtgCollections.Items(i).Cells(7).Text)
dgiOpr01Rep.Cells(7).Text = AddPrecZero(Math.Ceiling(val))
```

You need to use whatever numeric type matches the contents of the text though.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved yourproblem (by clicking on the green tick above)